# PHPUnit always run setUpDatabase every test method

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm just trying to add PHPUnit test for [my laravel package](https://github.com/HalalSoft/laravel-dynamic-column), but I dont know why `setUpDatabase()` from `TestCase` always run every test that extend from `TestCase` class.

Here is my `TestCase` class:

```
class  TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->setUpDatabase();
    }

    protected function setUpDatabase()
    {
        $this->app['db']->connection()->getSchemaBuilder()->create(
            'pages',
            function(Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('title');
                $table->text('content');
                $table->binary('options')->nullable();
            }
        );
    }

}
```

Here is my `PageModelTest` class :

```
class PageModelTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    /** @test */
    public function it_tests_right_row_count()
    {
        $pages = Page::all();

        $this->assertCount(3, $pages);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function it_tests_get_dynamic_column_data()
    {
        $page = Page::find(1);

        $this->assertIsArray($page->options);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function it_tests_create_data()
    {
        $pages = Page::create(
            [
                'title'   => "Another title dynamic column",
                'content' => 'This is another page content ',
                'options' => ['author' => 'Anonimous', 'okay'],
            ]
        );

        $this->assertCount(4, $pages);
    }

}
```

Every `PageModelTest` methods run will also run `setUpDatabase()` again and again. that make first method `it_tests_right_row_count` is success but other method return error like below:

> Halalsoft\LaravelDynamicColumn\Tests\PageModelTest::it_tests_get_dynamic_column_data
> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or
> view already exists: 1050 Table 'pages' already exists (SQL: create
> table `pages` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
> `title` varchar(255) not null, `content` text not null, `options` blob
> null))

I tried to add `use RefreshDatabase;` on the both class but still return same error.

I know I can check if the table is exist on `setUpDatabase()` but I don't think it's good practice.

Its normal behavior or any wrong with my codes?

Comment: @miken32 Sorry, but what is the reason you removed my full code link and also my final question? I was rollback

Comment: Why are you manually creating a table and not just using the RefreshDatabase trait with your migrations. I’d expect this to throw an error as the setUp method runs on each test but you’re not dropping the table after your tests.

Comment: @Unflux Usually on Laravel App project I always use migration,  Because this is just a simple package so I think doesnt need migration. Actually it's inspired from most packages from [spatie](https://github.com/spatie) always creating new table on test. an example [laravel-backup](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup/blob/master/tests/TestCase.php) which also creating a table on `setUpDatabase` . But spatie just use sqllite and I use mariadb. maybe I got error because I use mariadb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created that test case actually inspired from most packages from [Spatie](https://github.com/spatie)
that always creating new table on test. An example [laravel-backup](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup/blob/master/tests/TestCase.php) which also creating a table on `setUpDatabase`. But I didn't know if Spatie deleting the database every test case. So that I can answer my own questions:

> Its normal behavior or any wrong with my codes?

It's normal behavior,  my code is not wrong but need improvement if I don't want to create table every run test case method.

> I know I can check if the table is exist on `setUpDatabase()` but I don't think it's good practice.

Maybe it's not the best practice, but it's not the worst practice. The most of the git repo that I see do such thing.  So I think need to do this also in my repo/package.